# Scala: Help me understand comprehensions and case classes in this code

Tags: scala, case-class, for-comprehension

I am trying to wrap my head around Scala, and I am finding it quite challenging so far. I found this library (https://github.com/snowplow/scala-maxmind-geoip) I used in the past with Python for finding out stuff like the country base on an IP address.

So the example is pretty simple

```
import com.snowplowanalytics.maxmind.geoip.IpGeo

val ipGeo = IpGeo(dbFile = "/opt/maxmind/GeoLiteCity.dat", memCache = false, lruCache = 20000)

for (loc <- ipGeo.getLocation("213.52.50.8")) {
  println(loc.countryCode)   // => "NO"
  println(loc.countryName)   // => "Norway" 
}
```

And the documentation reads

> The getLocation(ip) method returns an IpLocation case class

So, if it is a case class, why this does not work?

```
val loc = ipGeo.getLocation("213.52.50.8")
println(loc.countryCode)
```

After all I can do

```
case class Team(team: String, country: String)
val u = Team("Barcelon", "Spain")
scala> u.country
res5: String = Spain
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please show the full method signature of `getLocation`. It probably returns a collection.

Comment: Actually as others suggested the signature is `private def getLocationWithoutLruCache(ip: String): Option[IpLocation]`

Comment: Well, yes. An `Option` is a special collection, containing zero or one element. That's the relationship to `foreach`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the documentation is just outdated there. If you look in [the code](https://github.com/snowplow/scala-maxmind-geoip/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/snowplowanalytics/maxmind/geoip/IpGeo.scala) it does not return a `IpLocation` but an `Option[IpLocation]`.

`Option` is a type from the scala standard library that has two constructors: `None` and `Some(value)`. So it is used where values are optional.

`for` in scala is just syntactic sugar. `for (x <- xs) { println(x) }` is translated into `xs.foreach(x => println(x))`. So you basically call the `foreach` on option, which executes your printlines if a value was returned by `getLocation`.

Comment: Great, much clearer now. Also bonus points for having explained how to access the damn thing. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`ipGeo.getLocation(...)` returns an `Option` type with the location inside.

Maybe if there is no location for the provided IP it will return `None`, if htere is a location it will return `Some(location)`

with the for comprehension you will get the value inside the `Option` type if there is a value or nothing if there isn't any value.